# Well formed json schema php_decode returns null ($ref is initiator of error)

Tags: php, json, validation, schema

I'm trying to decode well formed json below by json_decode , but it returns null. The problem in that place "tags": {"extends": {"$ref": 1}}, precisely $ref. If I remove $ then json_decode returns not null object.

But at the same time when I place $ref beyond "extends" at any other place - json_decode return not null result.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

```
{
  "$schema": "http:\/\/json-schema.org\/draft-03\/schema#",
  "id": 2,
    "name": "Site",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "id":           {"type": "integer","required": true},
        "entity_id":    {"type": "integer","required": true},
        "name":         {"type": "string", "required": true, "minLength": 5, "maxLength": 1024 },
        "tags": {
            "extends": {
                "$ref": 1
            }
        },        
        "address":      {"type": "string", "format": "uri", "required": true },
        "ftp_address":  {"type": "string", "format": "uri", "required": true },
        "ftp_login":    {"type": "string", "required": true },
        "ftp_password": {"type": "string", "required": true },
        "ftp_port":     {"type": "integer", "required": true },
        "ftp_protocol": {"type": "string", "required": true }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tryed debugging with json_last_error() or json_last_error_msg() ?

Comment: sure 
nothing more informative then I said